# Wordpress Multiple Post Type Loop shows same results on every page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, pagination, custom-post-type

So I am using WordPress with an underscores theme. I used code from twenty fourteen's theme with pagination.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'public_notices_paging_nav' ) ) :
function public_notices_paging_nav() {

global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;

// Don't print empty markup if there's only one page.
if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages < 2 ) {
    echo ("<h4 class='one-page-results'>End of Results</h4>");
    return;
}

$paged        = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$pagenum_link = html_entity_decode( get_pagenum_link() );
$query_args   = array();
$url_parts    = explode( '?', $pagenum_link );

if ( isset( $url_parts[1] ) ) {
    wp_parse_str( $url_parts[1], $query_args );
}

$pagenum_link = remove_query_arg( array_keys( $query_args ), $pagenum_link );
$pagenum_link = trailingslashit( $pagenum_link ) . '%_%';

$format  = $wp_rewrite->using_index_permalinks() && ! strpos( $pagenum_link, 'index.php' ) ? 'index.php/' : '';
$format .= $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ? user_trailingslashit( $wp_rewrite->pagination_base . '/%#%', 'paged' ) : '?paged=%#%';

// Set up paginated links.
$links = paginate_links( array(
    'base'     => $pagenum_link,
    'format'   => $format,
    'total'    => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'current'  => $paged,
    'mid_size' => 1,
    'add_args' => array_map( 'urlencode', $query_args ),
    'prev_text' => __( '&larr; Previous', 'public_notices' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Next &rarr;', 'public_notices' ),
    'type'      => 'list',
) );

if ( $links ) :

?>

<nav class="navigation paging-navigation" role="navigation">
    <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Posts navigation', 'public_notices' ); ?></h1>
    <?php echo $links; ?>
</nav><!-- .navigation -->
<?php
endif;
}endif;
```

This worked great when I only had one post type, but now I've made a loop that displays two post types and it works. But on every page its the same group of posts.

```
<?php
      $postLoop = array(
        'post_type' => array('public_notice_post', 'post'),
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $postLoop );
                 if ($query->have_posts()) :
                     while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
                     get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                endwhile; 

                public_notices_paging_nav();

                endif;

     wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Anything will help. I've tried a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the original problem of duplicated posts on every page all I had to do was write my code like this. HOWEVER I am still having an issue of page count, but that will addressed elsewhere.

```
        <?php  
        $page = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        $ppp = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );      

        if ( $page == 1 )
            $offset = 6;
        else
            $offset = 6 + ( $page - 1 ) * $ppp;
    ?>
    <?php
      $postLoop = array(
            'post_type' => array('public_notice_post', 'post'),
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page'=> $ppp,
            'offset' => $offset
    );

            $wp_query = new WP_Query( $postLoop );
                 if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
                     while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                     get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                endwhile; 

                public_notices_paging_nav();

                endif;


     wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got a loop with no "wp_reset_query()" and this may caused some bugs on other loop.. just look all your loop to be sure there noone without reset query.

On which kind of page you coded this loop ? This is a custom template or other ?

Sorry for my english, im french.